# Access, multiple iif functions in one

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

I am trying to come up with a new iif statement to have different logic, however I am getting 0's in my new table when I see records from 1 - Master that should have a balance.

1. If 1 - Master = 1234 then use "Balance"
2. If a record from 1 - Master <> 1234, then apply the isnull logic.
3. if a record is null , then use avg factor * balance
4. if a record is not null, then use factor * balance

```
IIf([1 - Master].rln='1234', [1 - Master].Balance, 
(IIf(IsNull([0 -  Month End Factors].Factor), [1 - Master].Balance*[0 -  Average Factors].[Avg Factor], [1 - Master].Balance*[0 -  Month End Factors].Factor)))  
AS [Final Balance]
```

Can anyone help with this? I am getting 0's after running this, perhaps my statement isnt correctly written.

Thanks.

Comment: Strongly advise not to use spaces nor special characters in naming convention nor begin names with numbers. Why is there a space showing at end of several instances of table name: `[1 - Master ]`? Provide sample data and desired output as text tables. Are you familiar with Nz() function?

Comment: '1234' is real data and rln is a text field?

Comment: 1234 is a numeric. and the space is just from me altering the table names abit, its not what my actual sql statement is.

Comment: If rln field is number type field, don't use apostrophes around 1234. Altering why - typo error? Edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see anything wrong with syntax but expression could be simpler. Consider:

```
IIf([1 - Master].rln='1234', [1 - Master].Balance, 
[1 - Master ].Balance * Nz([0 -  Month End Factors].Factor, [0 -  Average Factors].[Avg Factor])) 
AS [Final Balance]
```

Field names must be prefixed with table names only if multiple tables in query have same field names.

```
IIf([rln]='1234', [Balance], [Balance] * Nz([Factor], [Avg Factor])) AS [Final Balance]
```

IsNull() and Nz() are both VBA functions. To avoid calls to VBA in an SQL statement, use IS NULL.

```
IIf([rln]='1234', [Balance], [Balance] * IIf([Factor] IS NULL, [Avg Factor], [Factor])) AS [Final Balance]
```

If `rln` is number type field, don't use apostrophes around 1234.